# Convert DOY to mm-dd format

Tags: python, time

I have a problem with my date format. how can I convert day of year values to mm-dd format? For instance if my doy have a value of 161 this will be converted to 06-10 (June 10 for instance). And this can work with leap and non-leap years.

Comment: If my opinion means something: this question is related to Landsat data processing and such questions may be asked at gis.stackexchange. Landsat's scenes name contain DOY, which is hard to human read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a script for this task. It was developed for processing Landsat data.

Usage: `DATE(161, 2015)`

Prints string: `'2015.06.10'`

Here is a code (sorry, but comments and some messages are in russian):

```
# -*- coding: cp1251 -*-

# функция определения даты по году (ХХХХ) и дню (ХХХ) в формате: от 1 до 365(366)
def DATE(DAY, YEAR):
    DAY = int(DAY)
    YEAR = float(YEAR)

    # Y=1 - високосный
    # Y=0 - не високосный

    if (YEAR//400 == YEAR/400): # високосный
        Y=1

    elif (YEAR//4 == YEAR/4) and (YEAR//100 != YEAR/100): # високосный
        Y=1

    else: # не високосный
        Y=0

    # номер месяца  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
    MONTH_LEN   = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31] # количество дней в месяце

    # если не високосный, то в феврале 28 дней
    if Y==0:
        MONTH_LEN=MONTH_LEN

    else: # иначе в феврале 29 дней
        MONTH_LEN[1]+=1

    # выход если значение DAY вне рамок (1-366)
    if Y == 0 and (DAY > 365 or DAY < 1):
        import sys
        sys.exit(str(int(YEAR))+" Не високосный год. Значение дня больше 365 или меньше 1")

    if Y == 1 and (DAY > 366 or DAY < 1):
        import sys
        sys.exit(str(int(YEAR))+" Високосный год. Значение дня больше 366 или меньше 1")

    #определяем номер дня в месяце
    for N, M in enumerate(MONTH_LEN):
        if DAY > M:
            DAY = DAY-M
        else:
            M_NUM = N+1
            break

    if len(str(DAY)) == 1:
        DAY = '0' + str(DAY)
    else:
        DAY = str(DAY)

    if len(str(M_NUM)) == 1:
        M_NUM = '0' + str(M_NUM)
    else:
        M_NUM = str(M_NUM)

    return str(int(YEAR)) + "." + M_NUM+ "." + DAY

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass
```

Comment: Hi Mr. Che, will try your script. Thank you very much for sharing.